# OC command to remove multiple old tag(s) from an Image Stream?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I know `oc tag -d python:3.5` will remove only 3.5 tag.However I would like to remove multiple old tags from the same Image Stream using oc command.

*For instance image streams phython:rel-1, phython:rel-2, phython:rel-3.
I am trying like `oc tag -d python:rel-*`. But I end up with below error message.*

```
*Error from server (NotFound): imagestreamtags.image.openshift.io "rel-*" not found*
```

**I am wondering is there any way to apply wildcards for tags to remove multiple old tags in one go?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not fully tested, and you can't do it in one command invocation, but you can use a shell script something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

TAGS=`oc get is python --template='{{range .spec.tags}}{{" "}}{{.name}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}'`

for tag in $TAGS; do
    if [[ "$tag" = rel-* ]]; then
        oc tag python:$tag -d
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank You for the response. I have no idea about "--template='{{range .spec.tags}}{{" "}}{{.name}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}".  Could you please paste some links here to get in depth knowledge about "--template='{{range .spec.tags}}{{" "}}{{.name}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}"?

Comment: It is a Golang Template. Perhaps have a look through https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ to try and understand the format.